# Screen Reader reading properly on Mac chrome but not on Windows Chrome React

Tags: reactjs, windows, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I have a scenario where I have added an `aria-label` to a parent `<div>` which contains some text. Ideally the `aria-label` provided to the parent `<div>` should be narrated first and then the child Text component. This works completely fine on MacOS Chrome with the VoiceOver screen reader, but on Windows Chrome with NVDA the parent `<div>` `aria-label` is not at all read.

Attaching a code snippet for reference:

```
<div aria-label="Parent div accessibility">
     <Text> Some Text </Text> 
</div>
```

Speech output on MacOS Chrome with VoiceOver:

```
Narrator - Parent div accessibility
Narrator - Some Text
```

Speech output on Windows Chrome with NVDA:

```
Narrator - Some Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen readers are all over the map with respect to interpretting `aria-label` on non-interactive elements.

According to [David MacDonald's tests](https://davidmacd.com/blog/does-aria-label-override-static-text.html), VoiceOver and TalkBack will read the `aria-label` text on static elements, but JAWS and NVDA will not unless the static content (like a `<div>`) has the `role="navigation"`, `role="search"`, `role="main"`, or `role="img"`.

By design, `aria-label` is meant to override the existing text of an element because it is what most screen readers will interpret as the element's label. So, the behaviour you're getting from VoiceOver is not necessarily standard behaviour. Some screen readers (like TalkBack) will ignore the inner text of your `<div>` if you use `aria-label`, because it interprets the `aria-label` as the label for that element and ignores any other text within the element. Other screen readers like JAWS will read *both* the `aria-label` text and the inner text of the `<div>` *if* you add a role like `role="navigation"` to your static element. It seems that NVDA 2018 did support using `aria-label` on static elements, but it was later removed because there's yet to be consensus on the `aria-label` debate.

## Option 1

The fail-safe option would be to use text that is visibly hidden by CSS. This is fully supported by all browser/screen reader combinations.

Here is the example [suggested by WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/):

```
<style>
    .sr-only {
    position:absolute;
    left:-10000px;
    top:auto;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="sr-only">This text is hidden.</div>
```

## Option 2

Another option is to use the CSS `content` property to hide the text that you want spoken by the screen reader, as suggested by slugolicious in [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961940/make-screen-reader-read-out-a-prefix-text-along-with-dom-contents-when-using-rol):

```
<style>
    div::before {content: "This text is hidden"; font-size: 0px;}  
</style>
```

I tested his suggestion with JAWS and NVDA and it announced the "This text is hidden" text as well as the inner text of the `<div>`.

However, as QuentinC pointed out in the comments, the CSS `content` property isn't currently supported by all browser/screen reader combinations.

For reference:
[Clarify use of aria-label on elements with no role #756](https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/756)
[Woe-ARIA: The Surprisingly but Ridiculously Complicated World of aria-label/ledby](https://www.jantrid.net/2015/12/woe-aria-surprisingly-but-ridiculously.html)
[What happens with aria-labelledby, aria-label and aria-describedby on static HTML elements?](https://davidmacd.com/blog/does-aria-label-override-static-text.html)
[WebAIM: Invisible Content Just for Screen Reader Users](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)

### Update

I edited my original answer to include QuentinC's suggestion of using CSS to hide the text.

Comment: Note that CSS Content isn't read with all screen reader + browser combinations either. The best is to use visually hidden / off screen text technique, which work really everywhere.

Comment: @QuentinC thanks for the note. Do you know offhand which browser/screen reader combinations don't currently support the CSS `content` property? Would be good for future reference.

Comment: I don't have an exhaustive list, sorry, but I can at least confirm that CSS content isn't read on several versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE with Jaws. Maybe it works in recent versions, but not on older ones, and many Jaws users don't update as often as they ideally should (because of cost or lack of computer knowledge). Technically, it's debatable whether screen readers should read CSS contents, because CSS is supposed to be presentational stuff only.

Comment: Good to know. I've edited my answer to include your suggestion of using CSS to hide the text as a first resort, rather than only rely on the CSS `content` property technique.

Comment: @QuentinC If the CSS `content` is **not** read, it would be a browser bug.  The accessible name calculation specifically says that `content` (before or after) **MUST** be included in the text when the accessible name comes from content.  See step 2.F.ii in https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2

Comment: @slugolicious: I always thought the opposite and that Jaws were right, because many people are using CSS content to display unreadable characters such as logos and text icons. Thank you for making it clear that Jaws was wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GeorgeChapman. Seems like i was missing the role part.

Comment: @ankitasom No problem, however please be aware that adding the `role` attribute won't solve the problem for all browser/screen reader combinations (see my comment in my answer about NVDA not supporting this). My recommendation is that you use CSS to visibly hide the text you want to be spoken by screen readers (option 1) if you want it to be compatible with all screen reader/browser combinations.

Comment: Noted @GeorgeChapman. I personally couldn’t try out the solution with CSS due to time crunch but surely will do. Could you please tell me if the screen reader highlights the text that is hidden and not the whole div component. This can be misleading for the users who can partially visualise the screen.

Comment: @QuentinC, that is a valid point. It depends what the `content` is.  If it's normal printable text, then it absolutely should be announced by screen readers.  If the content is unprintable or a font-icon, then it might not be announced.  It would still be part of the accessible name but it might be characters that can't be announced.